# Specifying tests as build target in .NET Framework Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild, msbuild-task

I currently have a .NET Framework Application whose build process I'm trying to automate using jenkins. Is there a way to specify the tests in a Target in the Start-up project file so that I can specify a command like:

> msbuild /t:Test

and it will run the tests?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a new `proj` file, with **Test** Target.

For example, you will create a file at your repository root, call it `jenkins.build`, and put the following code in it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Test">
    <ItemGroup>
        <UnitTests Include="$(WorkingFolder)\**\bin\$(Configuration)\**\*.UnitTests.dll;" Exclude="$(WorkingFolder)\**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.*;"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <VSTestPath>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"</VSTestPath>
      <VSTestCommand>
          $(VSTestPath) @(UnitTests->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')
      </VSTestCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Exec Command="$(VSTestCommand)" ContinueOnError="false" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Then call this file with `msbuild jenkins.build /t:Test`.

(Of course, this file is defined a lot of things that are environment-dependent.)